# Pokemon Game. Trouble returning an array JAVA

Tags: java, methods, return

```
public static int wildPokemon(int opponentstats[] , int  rattataStats[] , int  geodudeStats[] , int  pidgeyStats[])
{
rattataStats = new int[]{27,42,35};
geodudeStats = new int[]{35,45,80};
pidgeyStats = new int[]{39,33,33};

System.out.println(".");
Pause(1000);
System.out.println(".");
Pause(1000);
System.out.println(".");
Pause(1000);   

Random wildPokemon = new Random();
int opponent = (wildPokemon.nextInt(3));
while(true)
{
if(opponent == 0)
{
 System.out.println("You have come across a wild Rattata!!!");
 rattataStats[0] = opponentstats[0];
 rattataStats[1] = opponentstats[1];
 rattataStats[2] = opponentstats[2];
 return opponentstats;

}
else if(opponent == 1)
{
  System.out.println("You have come across a wild Geodude!!!");
 geodudeStats[0] = opponentstats[0];
 geodudeStats[1] = opponentstats[1];
 geodudeStats[2] = opponentstats[2];
 return opponentstats;

}
else if(opponent ==-2)
{
  System.out.println("You have come across a wild Pidgey!!!");
 pidgeyStats[0] = opponentstats[0];
 pidgeyStats[1] = opponentstats[1];
 pidgeyStats[2] = opponentstats[2];
 return opponentstats;
}
}
}
```

I am so lost and frustrated. Why is it that I can't return opponentstats and it's values inside of it! Thanks for the help.

Comment: I am glad we could resolve this quickly :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method is declared to return int.

The variable you try to return is of type int[].

So either change the return type to array of int, or return a single int value (not an array!) instead.

Comment: Thanks you so much for the straight forward answer!! Very informative and easy to understand!